# How to make custom Video player in android with full screen(Landscape) and small screen(Portrait)?

Tags: android

I have use the given link

https://github.com/brightec/ExampleMediaController

but it not working as i expecting the result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are asking how make videoview fit fully in its Layout? or creating custom videoview? can't get what exactly you are asking

Comment: Create custom videoview